# Where is the appropriate place to put font-awesome files in React apps?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I downloaded the latest font-awesome 4.7 and extracted the files in my public folder of the react app. I linked it in the index.html like this `<link href="./fontawesome/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`. Should I be doing this? Or should I put these in a a folder within the src directory? I never quite understood what I should be putting in the public folder.

Comment: are you using create-react-app, or webpack, or something else ?

Comment: You should also look into using [react-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons) instead because it gives you access to icons from more libraries than just fontawesome.

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the well known open source projects for react \ react-native icons:

React: [react-icons](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons)

React-Native: [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

You should then import only the icon you want, for example (from Font Awesome):

```
import FaBeer from 'react-icons/lib/fa/beer';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use command prompt & install using NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome.

And then just include using `var FontAwesome = require('react-fontawesome')`
You also need to include below stylesheet in index.html.

> font-awesome.min.css

I have used this in my project & it turned out quite well.